# Using xev in an existing window with the -id option

Tags: window, xev

The **xev** man page states: “You can also attach it to an existing window... The '**-id** *windowid*' option specifies that the window with the given *id* should be monitored, instead of creating a new window.”

I'm looking for an acceptable argument for the **-id** option, but none of them seem to work.
I got: "X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)"

The **screen** man page also talks about a *windowid* argument to be used with the **select** option: “Switch to the window identified by *WindowID*. This can be a prefix of a window title (alphanumeric window name) or a window number... There are two special WindowIDs, "**-**" selects the internal blank window and "**.**" selects the current window.”
So I tried with **.** but I got : "unable to parse argument '**.**' for -id"

(versions : Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS - GNOME 3.28.2 - xev 1.2.2)

Answer (score 2):

Run `xwininfo` and then click on any window and it should show you details including the `Window ID`.